# How to parallalise partitioning around medoids (PAM) using a precalculated distance matrix

Tags: r, parallel-processing, cluster-analysis, partitioning, dtw

I am trying to cluster income trajectories using a large longitudinal dataset containing participants’ yearly reported incomes.

I have chosen to calculate distances between the trajectories using dynamic time warping and have successfully parallelised this process using the function `proxy::dist` from the package `dtwclust` (see Stage 2 below).

I have also been able to calculate PAM clusters for k=2:40 using a regular for loop with no parallelisation (see Stage 3 below). However, if possible, I would like to parallelise this stage of my analysis as well to save time.

**Does anyone have any suggestions for how I can parallelise this clustering process?**

P.S. I have tried using `tsclust` from the package `dtwclust`. This does successfully parallelise the clustering. However it also seems to crash my R session if I put in too many separate values for k. If anyone is aware of a clustering function in `dtwclust` that will accept a pre-calculated distance matrix as input, that would be ideal. Though of course any other solutions are also very welcome!

**EXAMPLE CODE**

***Stage 1: Import libraries and format data***

```
# Import required libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(dtwclust)
library(parallel)
library(cluster)

# Set seed for reproducible results
set.seed(123)
# Generate different lengths of sample income trajectories
lengths  = sample(7:10,500,replace = T) %>% as.list()
# Use rnorm to generate income trajectories of varying lengths, as defined above
inc_traj = list() %>% .[1:500] %>% map2(lengths, ~ rnorm(.y, 1588.647, 1484.186))
```

***Stage 2: Calculate distance matrix (parallelised)***

```
# Set up parallelisation
# Code taken from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dtwclust/vignettes/parallelization-considerations.html

# create multi-process workers
workers <- makeCluster(detectCores())
# load dtwclust in each one, and make them use 1 thread per worker
invisible(clusterEvalQ(workers, {
    library(dtwclust)
    RcppParallel::setThreadOptions(1L)
}))
# register your workers, e.g. with doParallel
require(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(workers)

# Calculate distance matrix
distmat = proxy::dist(inc_traj, method = "dtw_basic")
```

***Stage 3: Calculate PAM clusters (not parallelised)***

```
# Create empty list to be populated with clusters
clusters = list()

# For loop which calculates partitions around medoids for k=2:40
for (i in 2:40) {
  clusters[[i]] = distmat %>% pam(k=i, diss=T)
  cat("\r",paste0(i," of 40 clusters calculated."))
}
```

Comment: You should read that vignette more closely, `dtw_basic` never benefits from multi-processing, it's only multi-threaded. The [helpers for control parameters](https://rdrr.io/cran/dtwclust/man/tsclust-controls.html) accept pre-calculated distance matrices in `distmat`.

Comment: @Alexis thanks for the response and clarification. I hadn't previously been aware of the distinction between multi-processing and multi-threading, so that is useful to understand. I was aware of the control parameters, but wasn't sure how to implement them. However, I found some examples [here](https://github.com/asardaes/dtwclust/blob/master/man-examples/tsclust-examples.R) which I'll experiment with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I’ve managed to successfully pass a precalculated distance matrix to the function `tsclust` with help from @Alexis and code from the `dtwclust` github page [here](https://github.com/asardaes/dtwclust/blob/master/man-examples/tsclust-examples.R). My solution is below for anyone else who’s interested.

***Stage 4: Calculate PAM clusters (parallelised)***

```
# Define vector number of clusters as integers
ks = c( 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L,10L,11L,12L,13L,14L,15L,16L,17L,18L,19L,20L,
       21L,22L,23L,24L,25L,26L,27L,28L,29L,30L,31L,32L,33L,34L,35L,36L,37L,38L,39L,40L)

# Create empty list to be populated with clusters
clusters = list()

# For loop which calculates partitions around medoids for k=2:40
for (i in 2:40) {
  clusters[[i]] = tsclust(inc_traj, k = ks[i], distance = "dtw_basic", centroid = "pam",
                          control = partitional_control(distmat = distmat), seed = 3247, trace = TRUE)
  cat("\r",paste0(i," of 40 clusters calculated."))
}
```

I also compared the processing time of both the `tsclust` method outlined in Stage 4 above to the `pam` method outlined in Stage 3 of the original question for k=2:4. I did this on my full dataset of 34,591 trajectories and found the `tsclust` approach was substantially faster, so will be using that moving forward. I’ve reported the processing times in the below table in case others are interested, though it’s probably noting I have access to a machine with 28 CPU cores, so time differences may be less dramatic on regular desktops.

```
_______________________________
| Method  | k |      Time      |
| tsclust | 2 | 18.584 seconds |
| tsclust | 3 | 25.746 seconds |
| tsclust | 4 | 15.37  seconds |
|   pam   | 2 | 6.195  minutes |
|   pam   | 3 | 6.231  minutes |
|   pam   | 4 | 9.658  minutes |
_______________________________
```